# Cordova Android Background Service can't be found

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to create a service that a Cordova plugin can launch that will run in the background. First I created a service that extends IntentService:

```
public class BackgroundService extends IntentService {
 @Override
 protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Log.d(LOG_PREFIX, "handling an intent " + intent.toString());
    this.runBackgroundService();
   }
 public static Intent getServiceIntent(Context context){
  Intent intent = new Intent();
  intent.setClass(context, BackgroundService.class);
  return intent;
 }
}
```

Then in my plugin.xml file, I need to declare the Service in the manifest:

```
  <config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/manifest/application">
  <service
    android:name="com.myapp.BackgroundService"
    android:exported="false">
  </service>
</config-file>
```

Finally, in the plugin I fire off the background service by getting the Intent and calling startService:

```
public class PluginMain extends CordovaPlugin{
   public void initialize(CordovaInterface cordova, CordovaWebView webview){
      super.initialize(cordova, webview);
      Intent backgroundIntent = BackgroundService.getServiceIntent(cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext());
      cordova.getActivity().startService(backgroundIntent);
}
```

The issue is that the startService call is failing, saying it can't find the BackgroundService class, or that it's undeclared in the manifest. The weird thing is it's prepending some ionic string to the front of the class name:

> Unable to find explicit activity class {com.ionicframework.project165251/com.myapp.BackgroundService};

But if I try putting that explicit class (with the com.ionicframework.project165251/ prefix) it rejects it, saying slashes are invalid in manifest files. I'm at a loss for what to do...